# Different result on comparing errors to nil

Tags: go, null

I've tried to cast `nil` (of type `*MyError`) to error. By comparing the value of cast variable to nil, the result is different. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyError struct {
    err error
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return e.err.Error()
}

func nilErr() *MyError {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    e := nilErr()
    fmt.Println(e) // <nil>
    fmt.Println(error(e)) // <nil>

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", e) // (*main.MyError)(nil)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", error(e)) // (*main.MyError)(nil)

    fmt.Println(e == error(e)) // true

    fmt.Println(e == nil) // true
    fmt.Println(error(e) == nil) // false
}
```

playground: [try code](https://play.golang.org/p/Oa1p0zWWUIC)

The strange part is that the comparison of `e` to `error(e)` returns `true` but comparing each of them to `nil` gives different results.

Is there something wrong with the cast? If yes, How should it be done?